# Let $A⊆B⊆C$ and $X<Y$ denote $X$ is an elementary substructure of $Y.$ Does $A<B$ and $A<C$ imply $B<C$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C $ and $X<$Y denote $X$ is an elementary substructure of $Y$. Does $A < B$ and $A < C$ $\implies B<C$? My inkling is that this is not true. Here is why:

$A<B$ means for any sentence $\phi(\overline{x})$, $A \models \phi(\overline{a})$ iff $B \models \phi(\overline{a})$ for any tuple $\overline{a} \in A$.

Similarly,

$A<C$ means for any sentence $\psi(\overline{x})$, $A \models \psi(\overline{\alpha})$ iff $C \models \psi(\overline{\alpha})$ for any tuple $\overline{\alpha} \in A$.

We want to show that for any $\theta(\overline{x})$, $B \models \theta(\overline{b})$ iff $C \models \theta(\overline{b})$ for any tuple $\overline{b} \in B$.

From the first two we can only conclude that for any $\theta(\overline{x})$, $B \models \theta(\overline{\text{a}})$ iff $C \models \theta(\overline{\text{a}})$ for any tuple $\overline{\text{a}} \in A$, but not for any tuple $\overline{b} \in B$.

However, I cannot think of a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  Let $A$ be $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ and let $C$ be any nontrivial elementary extension of $A$.  Then every element of $C\setminus A$ has a predecessor and a successor (since every element of $A$ besides $0$ has a predecessor and a successor).  Pick an element $c\in C$ and let $B=C\setminus \{c\}$.  Note then that $B$ is isomorphic to $C$ via an isomorphism that fixes $A$: just send every element of $C$ that is less than $c$ to itself, and every element of $C$ that is greater than $c$ to its predecessor.  So since $A\preceq C$, $A\preceq B$ as well.  But $B\not\preceq C$: if $b$ is the predecessor of $c$ and $d$ is the successor of $c$, then $B\models\text{"$b$ is the predecessor of $d$"}$ but $C$ does not.

Comment: "C be any nontrivial elementary extension of A". What would this look like?

Comment: Also how can we have B = C/A? Then A would not be a subset of B.

Comment: Oops, I wrote the wrong definition of $B$.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: You don't need to know anything about what $C$ looks like to understand this proof.  But it turns out it will look like $\mathbb{N}$ followed by a bunch of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.  More precisely, the order type will be $\mathbb{N}+L\times\mathbb{Z}$ where $L$ is some totally ordered set and $L\times\mathbb{Z}$ is ordered lexicographically.

Comment: Ok I literally just started model theory so not sure what an order type is. But since I am new to this I would like a more concrete example. So C = Z, A = N, B = C\{-1} would work correct? I guess the root of the problem comes down to me not having the intuition as to whether r not the identity function is an elementary embedding.

Comment: @pmac No, because $\mathbb{N}$ is not an elementary substructure of $\mathbb{Z}$ ($\mathbb{N}$ has a least element, while $\mathbb{Z}$ does not).

Comment: @Alex Kruckman I understand that N  ⊨ ∀x(x≥0) and Z ⊨ ¬∀x(x≥0) (I am adding 0 to the vocab), but we are only worried about if N ⊨ ϕ(n) implies Z ⊨ ϕ(n)  for any tuple n in N. So letting ϕ(x) = x≥0 we certainly have N and Z model ϕ(n). So why should the least element matter here?

Comment: @pmac: "Order type" just means ordered set up to isomorphism.  A concrete example of what $C$ could be is $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}$, which means you take a copy of $\mathbb{N}$ and then put a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ after it (i.e., you say every element of the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ is greater than every element of the copy of $\mathbb{N}$).  If you like, you could think of this as $\mathbb{N}$ together with elements "$\infty+n$" for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, ordered in the "obvious" way.

Comment: @pmac: Consider $\phi(x)$ which is $\forall y(y\geq x)$.  Then $\mathbb{N}\models\phi(0)$ but $\mathbb{Z}\not\models\phi(0)$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Ok. I think I have an example that better fits my limited understanding of structure relations. Let C be the graph with vertices 1,2,3 such that ∀x∀y(x≠y⟹E(x,y)). Let A be the graph 1 and 2 with R(1,2) and let B be the graph 1,2,3 with with R(1,2) but 3 disconnected from 1 and 2. Then A<C and A<B but not B<C

Comment: @pmac: That doesn't work.  Your $A$ and $B$ are not even substructures of $C$ (a substructure would have to have the same edge relation, just restricted to a subset of the domain).  More generally, there won't be any example with *finite* structures: if $C$ is finite (say with $n$ elements), then $A\preceq C$ implies $A=C$, since you can write a sentence $\varphi$ that says your structure has exactly $n$ elements and then $A\models\varphi$ iff $C\models\varphi$.

Comment: @pmac: No. It is true that $A$ is a substructure of $C$ (sorry I said it wasn't in my previous comment, I misread something).  But it is not an elementary substructure.  For instance, $A\models\forall x(x=1\vee x=2)$ but $C$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example. The structure in question is a bit simpler in my opinion. The verification is definitely harder, but it's a good exercise.

---

Consider a language with a single binary relation symbol $E$. Let $T$ be the first-order theory in this language whose models are the structures in this language in which:

- $E$ is an equivalence relation,
- every $E$-class has either $1$ or $2$ elements, and
- each of the two possible types of equivalence class occurs infinitely often.

(Whipping up such a $T$ is a good exercise.)

For the rest of this answer, restrict attention to models of $T$.

Let $A$ be some infinite model of $T$, and let $B$ be an extension of $A$ gotten by adding a new element $v$ not $E$-related to anything in $A$ (so $B$ *adds a class* to $A$). Now let $C$ be the extension of $B$ gotten by adding a new element $w$ and $E$-relating $w$ to $v$ (so $C$ adds an element to $B$ but does *not* add a new equivalence class). Clearly $B\not\preccurlyeq C$:

> The sentence-with-parameters $\forall x(vEx\leftrightarrow v=x)$ is true in $B$ but not in $C$.

On the other hand, it's a good exercise to show that $A\preccurlyeq B$ and $A\preccurlyeq C$. One way to do this is via automorphisms, via (proving and checking the applicability of) the following:

> **Lemma**. Let $X, Y$ be **isomorphic** structures with $X\subseteq Y$ *(remember that it's perfectly possible for a structure to be isomorphic to a proper substructure of itself - take e.g. $(\mathbb{R},<)$ vs. $((0,1), <)$)*. Suppose that for each finite tuple $a_1,...,a_n\in X$ there is an isomorphism $f:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f(a_i)=a_i$ for each $1\le i\le n$. Then $X\preccurlyeq Y$.

*HINT: isomorphisms preserve satisfaction of formulas ...*